# Remove dependency from a dependent variable

Tags: r, exploratory-data-analysis, boxplot, dependent-variable

I am tasked with doing some exploratory data analysis on the `Diamond` dataset from the [`library(Ecdat)`](https://rdrr.io/cran/Ecdat/) in R. The assignment states:

> Draw boxplots with notches for the prices of the diamonds grouped by variable `clarity`. Note that the price is trivially higher for heavier diamonds, and thus the weight (variable `carat`) needs to be subtracted out. This could be done by considering `price/carat` instead of `price`, but this solution might still not be optimal, and thus other approaches should be tested as well. (Hint: the normalized price should not show a dependency from the variable `carat`).

Now I drew the boxplots and a scatterplot to see how `carat` affected `price`.

```r
library(Ecdat)
data(Diamond)
boxplot(price ~ clarity, data = Diamond, notch = TRUE)
plot(price ~ carat, data = Diamond, col = as.numeric(clarity), 
     pch = as.numeric(clarity) + 14)
abline(lm(price ~ carat, data = Diamond)) # only for reference since 
                                          # not homoscedastic
```

[image: Price vs clarity]

[image: Price vs weight]

Since the relationship isn't really linear I see why `price/carat` might not be ideal and plotting `(price/carat) ~ carat` still shows a dependency.

So my real question is how "normalize the price" without being dependent on `carat`? I played around and

```r
plot(
  (price/carat^1.5) ~ carat,
  data = Diamond,
  col = as.numeric(clarity),
  pch = as.numeric(clarity) + 14
)
```

gives a "random looking" scatterplot but that is no real justification here. How do I remove the dependency from `carat`? Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

I guess an option could be to regress price on weight using GLM with an appropriate distribution family (`glm(price ~ weight, familiy= ...)`) and then use the residuals from the model as "adjusted" price. If you have enough data points you could otherwise fit a loess smoothing curve and, again, work with the residuals.

---

Example using the `diamonds` dataset included in `ggplot2`. This is the "raw" price vs carat:

```
library(mgcv)
library(ggplot2)

data(diamonds)

gg <- ggplot(data= diamonds, aes(x= carat, y= price)) +
    geom_point(pch= '.') +
    geom_smooth() +
    theme_light()
```

[image]

Now I adjust the price for carat. I follow ggplot's method of using a generalised additive model (gam) as smoother and use the residuals of the model as adjusted price:

```
fit <- gam(price ~ s(carat, bs= 'cs'), data= diamonds)

diamonds$carat_adj_price <- fit$residuals

gg <- ggplot(data= diamonds, aes(x= carat, y= carat_adj_price)) +
    geom_point(pch= '.') +
    geom_smooth() +
    theme_light()
```

[image]

```
par(mfcol= c(2, 1))
boxplot(price ~ clarity, data = diamonds, notch = TRUE, outline= FALSE)
boxplot(carat_adj_price ~ clarity, data = diamonds, notch = TRUE, outline= FALSE)
```

The correlation between price and carat has been removed even if higher carats show higher variance. Now a positive price means the diamond has a higher value given its weight.

Finally this is a comparison between original and adjusted price for clarity:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Interesting, I don't think I am familiar with the usage of residuals as a normalized value. Or do you mean the predicted values from the model? On the other hand wouldn't this still depend on `carat`?

Comment: @MatthiasPichler I expanded my answer - see if it makes sense!